# Retrieve local RPC server's PID given a handle/stringbinding

Tags: c, windows, rpc

Given a string binding for a local rpc binding handle, say 
"ncalrpc:SuperServer" we can get a handle and make a call on that server. Is there any way to get the PID of the server on the other side of the handle?

A call to [I_RpcBindingInqLocalClientPID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be used to get the client's PID, is there something that could be thought of as I_RpcBindingInqLocalServerPID  ?